# Testdisk and eCryptfs single files

Tags: ecryptfs, testdisk, photorec

Recently i've recovered my Downloads directory with testdisk but all files recovered are in .eCryptfs file extension. Now i need to decrypt it for find my PHP lost files, how I can do it?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to AU! Can you please describe your previous setup to us concerning ecryptfs? Could/can you recover the content of `~/.ecryptfs` in particular `wrapped-passphrase`?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment, yes i've in `~/.ecryptfs` the file `wrapped-passphrase`: `-rw------- 1 mirko mirko 48 Jul 28 09:14 .ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase`

Comment: Do you think that if I re-mount my home directory with the encrypted files **moved** in `~/.Private` with the `ecryptfs-mount-private` command I can recover all the files?

Comment: That's possible. If you use the `ecryptfs-mount-private` method, the path of the files is irrelevant.

Comment: No, it doesn't, i've mounted and decrypted the home partition, but in my recoveredFiles directory the files are still the same.
Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18145/discussion-between-mirko-and-david-foerster).